# Treeview into Pygtk Tab

Tags: python, linux, treeview, gtk, pygtk

i have a problem with Pygtk, how can i put a Treeview into a Pygtk notebook tab.

I want the treeview with the mysql connection of the first code code to this pygtk notebook tab, the first one that is called "Home" in the second code.

I don't know how to make this, please someone help me.

1) http://pastebin.com/ntZY51Ym

2) http://pastebin.com/t5p3sCqf

Comment: You'll need to add more details: what exactly is the problem you are experiencing? Your Notebook example is using GTK 2, so you'll need to modify it a little (starting with `from gi.repository import Gtk`) but otherwise there's no visible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a button to the 'home' page create a scrolled window as you do in the first example and add that to the notebook. Then add your treeview to the scrolled window.